# How do i get a list of all codecs available in ffmpeg?

Tags: c++, c, c++-cli

I have this code example I'm using in C:

```
//#define  UINT64_C  (uint64_t);

#pragma comment(lib, "Gdi32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "gdiplus.lib")

#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <GdiPlusEnums.h>

using namespace Gdiplus;


extern "C" {

#include  "libavcodec\avcodec.h"
#include "libavutil\mathematics.h"
//#include "libavcodec\avcodec.h"

WCHAR *fname;
AVCodec *codec;
AVCodecContext *c= NULL;
int i, ret, x, y, got_output;
int total_frame_counter;
FILE *f;
AVFrame *frame;
AVPacket pkt;
int codec_id;
uint8_t endcode[] = { 0, 0, 1, 0xb7 };
int errn;

void Encoder_init()
{
   avcodec_register_all();
    /* find the mpeg1 video encoder */

   codec_id = CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO;

    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO);
    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Codec not found\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!c) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video codec context\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* put sample parameters */
    c->bit_rate = 400000;
    /* resolution must be a multiple of two */
    c->width = 352;
    c->height = 288;
    /* frames per second */
    
   //c->time_base= (AVRational){1,25};
   c->time_base.num=1;c->time_base.den=25;
   
    c->gop_size = 10; /* emit one intra frame every ten frames */
    c->max_b_frames=1;
   c->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
   /*
    if(codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
        av_opt_set(c->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);
      */
}

const char *Encoder_GetCodecName( int id )
{
   
   return avcodec_get_name( (AVCodecID)id );
}
```

Then I have a header file in c++:

```
const char *Encoder_GetCodecName( int id );
```

Then I have another header file of the C++ where I'm using the `GetCodecName()` to get the List:

```
List<String^> ^GetCodecs()
   {
      List<String^> ^l = gcnew List<String^>;

      String ^s;

      for (int i=0;i<3333;i++)
      {
      s = gcnew String(Encoder_GetCodecName( i ));
      l->Add(s);
      }

      return l;
   }
```

But I did now `i<3333` so maybe one the of indexes are empty since there are less than 3333 codecs?

So how can I get/calculate how many codecs there are in the ffmpeg library so I will do something like for example:

```
i < codecs.Length
```

and not use `3333`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AVCodecID` is an enum.  It has a finite number of values that it defines.  However, a lot of those values are not sequential, there are several gaps in between values, and also there are values that go well into 6 digit numbers (the highest being 0x21000 ie 135168).  There is no mechanism in libav's API to find out the highest available `AVCodecID` value, so if you want to stick with an ID loop then you need to increase your loop counter quite a bit.  Also, `avcodec_get_name()` returns `"unknown_codec"` for unknown IDs, so you need to filter those out before adding them to your list.  Or you can incorporate a `switch` statement into your loop with hard-coded `case` statements for known ID values.

A better approach is not to loop through the IDs at all, but to instead loop through the registered codecs themselves.  Call `av_codec_next()` to get a pointer to the first registered [`AVCodec`](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVCodec.html) struct. `AVCodec` has [`name`](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVCodec.html#ad3daa3e729850b573c139a83be8938ca) and [`long_name`](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVCodec.html#acb4afcfce3b6541ed70aa7f21d507422) fields.  Then call `av_codec_next()` again to get the next `AVCodec`, and so on, until it returns a NULL pointer.  [The documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__core.html#ga15369ce1a486dd26a14a043c2b4d7e76) states:

> AVCodec* av_codec_next    (   const AVCodec *     c   )
>
> If c is NULL, returns the first registered codec, if c is non-NULL,
> returns the next registered codec after c, or NULL if c is the last
> one.

By accessing the `AVCodec` structs directly, your loop will run much faster and more accurately, and it will also allow you to distinguish between encoders and decoders, which may share common names.

Try something like this:

```cpp
__declspec(thread) AVCodec* current_codec = NULL;
    
const char* Encoder_GetNextCodecName()
{
    current_codec = av_codec_next(current_codec);
    while (current_codec != NULL)
    {
        /* this is optional...
        if (!av_codec_is_encoder(current_codec))
        {
            current_codec = av_codec_next(current_codec);
            continue;
        }
        */
        return current_codec->name;
    }
    return "";
}
    
const char* Encoder_GetFirstCodecName()
{
    current_codec = NULL;
    return Encoder_GetNextCodecName();
}
```

```cpp
List<String^> ^GetCodecs()
{
    List<String^> ^l = gcnew List<String^>;
    
    String ^s = gcnew String(Encoder_GetFirstCodecName());
    while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        l->Add(s);
        s = gcnew String(Encoder_GetNextCodecName());
    }
    
    return l;
}
```

**UPDATE:** as `av_codec_next()` was deprecated several years ago, you can use [`av_codec_iterate()`](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__core.html#ga7cd040fcc147340186deb0c54dc996b0) instead, eg:

```cpp
__declspec(thread) void* iterate_data = NULL;
    
const char* Encoder_GetNextCodecName()
{
    AVCodec* current_codec = av_codec_iterate(&iterate_data);
    while (current_codec != NULL)
    {
        /* this is optional...
        if (!av_codec_is_encoder(current_codec))
        {
            current_codec = av_codec_iterate(&iterate_data);
            continue;
        }
        */
        return current_codec->name;
    }
    return "";
}

const char* Encoder_GetFirstCodecName()
{
    iterate_data = NULL;
    return Encoder_GetNextCodecName();
}
```

Comment: I can see an `av_codec_next()` function in the headers, but the linked documentation doesn't seem to show such a function. Was it replaced by something else in newer versions?

Comment: I suppose I still have the old version too. The newer version uses: [av_codec_iterate](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__core.html#ga7cd040fcc147340186deb0c54dc996b0).

Comment: @AlexisWilke [`av_codec_next()`](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.0/group__lavc__core.html#ga424c2b3c23cc41f4ef93ef2034f5c901). But yes, it was deprecated several years ago, `av_codec_iterate()` is the new function. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Note that since C++11, you should use `thread_local ...` instead of the Microsoft specific `__declspec(thread) ...`.

Answer (score 8):

ffmpeg/avconv has an option -codecs that runs show_codecs() from cmdutils.c

It lists everything in the following format:

```
Codecs:
 D..... = Decoding supported
 .E.... = Encoding supported
 ..V... = Video codec
 ..A... = Audio codec
 ..S... = Subtitle codec
 ...S.. = Supports draw_horiz_band
 ....D. = Supports direct rendering method 1
 .....T = Supports weird frame truncation
 ------
 D V D  4xm             4X Movie
 D V D  8bps            QuickTime 8BPS video
 D A D  8svx_exp        8SVX exponential
 D A D  8svx_fib        8SVX fibonacci
 D V D  FRWU            Forward Uncompressed
  EV    a64multi        Multicolor charset for Commodore 64
  EV    a64multi5       Multicolor charset for Commodore 64, extended with 5th color (colram)
 DEA D  aac             Advanced Audio Coding
 D A D  aac_latm        AAC LATM (Advanced Audio Codec LATM syntax)
 D V D  aasc            Autodesk RLE
 DEA D  ac3             ATSC A/52A (AC-3)
  EA    ac3_fixed       ATSC A/52A (AC-3)
 D A D  adpcm_4xm       ADPCM 4X Movie
 DEA D  adpcm_adx       SEGA CRI ADX ADPCM
 D A D  adpcm_ct        ADPCM Creative Technology
...
```

you can use show_codecs() from cmdutils.c as a template to get what you need